# Listening for useState default value event

Tags: reactjs, input, dom-events, react-hooks

I would like to know how to get the updated `labelRef` within a function, namely `inputBlur()`

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("Type...");
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = useState();
  const labelRef = useRef();

  const inputChange = e => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    setLabelWidth(labelRef.current.offsetWidth);
  };

  const inputBlur = e => {
    const trimmed = e.target.value.trim();
    if (trimmed) {
      setInputValue(trimmed);
    } else {
      setInputValue("Type...");
    }
    setLabelWidth(labelRef.current.offsetWidth);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLabelWidth(labelRef.current.offsetWidth);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Type below to see if input and div is the same width</p>
      <div ref={labelRef}>{inputValue}</div>
      <br />
      <input
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={e => inputChange(e)}
        onBlur={e => inputBlur(e)}
        style={{ width: `${labelWidth}px` }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

To explain this example a bit, there is an input field that changes its width by filling a `div` with the same text.  Currently, it doesn't work right when the input field is empty followed by an `onblur` event.  The input field should be filled with the default `useState` value, `"Type..."`, but the input field width is 0.

The problem I see is that in `inputBlur` function, after triggering `setInputValue`, the line `labelRef.current.offsetWidth` still reflects the old element, since it has not yet re-rendered that element.

Here is the [link to the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-wood-ttvrv?fontsize=14) of this example to try replicating this problem.

My issue comes from the lack of understanding the flow of react hook.  I need to capture the event after `useState` has updated the element with its default value, and then calculate the width.

Note: I do not want the input to automatically fill in the empty input field with the default value while still in focus.  It must be filled in on an `onBlur()` event.

Comment: why do you need `setLabelWidth` instead of just using the ref `style={{ width: \`${labelRef.current.offsetWidth}px\` }}`?

Comment: I think `labelRef` is accessible initially in componentDidMount, as in useEffect.  Although I can get `labelRef` initially like you noted, `labelRef.current` returns undefined.  Is my assessment right? Were you able to get it to work that way?

Comment: right, it would need to be `labelRef.current?.offsetWidth` or a good old `labelRef.current && labelRef.current.offsetWidth`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure if I got your question right, so it's like an assumption.

The root cause: you are calling both `setInputValue` and `setLabelWidth` in the same place - input handler. But `setInputValue` will update label with new value only on next render. So it takes `labelWidth` for previous value.

It happens not only when you emptify value - you may see that input's width changes inconsistently while typing.

Make it separate `useEffect`:

```
  const inputBlur = e => {
    const trimmed = e.target.value;
    if (trimmed) {
      setInputValue(trimmed);
    } else {
      setInputValue("Type...");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLabelWidth(labelRef.current.offsetWidth);
  }, [inputValue])
```

Comment: Oddly I faced an issue with whitespace in the code sandbox I provided, but no issues in my actual project.

Comment: I think the reason why this is correct is because setting state from the `onChange` and `onBlur` events cause a re-render which in effect triggers the `useEffect` whenever the `inputValue` changes.  Since we're accessing the `ref` in there after the `componentDidUpdate`, the width state is being correctly set.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in `inBlur` function, you are updating`labeWidth` with the div's current offsetWidth which is always 0 after an empty input followed by an onBlur event. Change to this: `setLabelWidth(labelWidth);`

Another way is moving `ref={labelRef}` to input element: `<input ref={labelRef} />`. See the official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)